# How to use istringstream twice

Tags: c++, string, istringstream

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ - repeatedly using istringstream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2767298/c-repeatedly-using-istringstream)

Given this code  :

```
   string line;  // for the line
   ifstream myfile ("input.txt");
   int algorithmNumber , matrixDim;
   getline (myfile,line);
   istringstream buffer(line);
   buffer >> algorithmNumber;
```

I read one line and then convert that line from string to int .

But if I want to read the next line and do that again :

```
   buffer(line);
   buffer >> matrixDim;
```

I get this : `no match for call to '(std::istringstream {aka std::basic_istringstream<char>}) (std::string&)'`

How can I read the next line and convert it into int with `istringstream` ?

Regards

Comment: Why not just create a new `istringstream` object?

Comment: taht's not the answer, the correct answer is to use str(). You also have to clear any flags that were set whilst parsing the previous string.