# Issues in using istringstream

Tags: c++, input, fstream, sstream

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std ;

int main()
{
    ifstream infile ;
    infile.open("input.txt") ; 
    string line ; 

    int noOfVar,noOfCubes  ; 

    getline(infile,line) ; 
    istringstream iss(line) ; 
    iss >> noOfVar ; 

    getline(infile,line) ; 
    iss(line) ; 
    iss >> noOfCubes ; 

    cout << noOfCubes ; 
    cout << noOfVar  ; 

    return 0 ; 
}
```

I have an input file as follows

```
6 
4
```

Why isn't the above code working on that . I have declared the `iss` object once . Can't I use that again ? It is presently showing error in compilation .

Comment: Generally, one does not put a space between the end of the line and the `;` in C++.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2767298/c-repeatedly-using-istringstream

Comment: Thanks a lot a guys for the reference . Should I delete this question ?

Comment: This doesn't compile.

Comment: @AbKDs I don't really think you should delete your question. You should at least clarify, which particular compiler error you got on which line. _'Doesn't work`_ is a bit too vague :-/ ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot initialize the `iss` variable again using the constructor method:

```
iss(line) ;
```

You'll need to have another instance of `std::istringstream` for the second line, or
alternatively you can use the [`std::istringstream::str()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream/str) function to set the contents (see here for a [working sample](http://ideone.com/oHOhgA)).