# C++ - Does resetting stringstream not reset the get position or clear flags?

Tags: c++, stringstream

I was extracting values from a stringstream in a loop, resetting the stringstream at the top of the loop every time the loop executed. However, the stringstream's `>>` operator fails at the second iteration every time. This distilled version of the code reproduces the problem I'm having:

```
istringstream word;
string in;
int number;

while(cin >> in) {

   word.str(in);

   //Uncommenting either one of the following lines seems to solve the issue:
   //word.clear();
   //word.seekg(0);

   word >> number;

   if(word.fail()) {
       cerr << "Failed to read int" << endl;
       return 1;
   }

   cout << in << ' ' << number << endl;
}
```

As it stands, it always fails on second loop iteration. However, uncommenting any one of the two commented lines of code solves the issue. What I don't get is, since I've reset the stringstream with `word.str(in)`, why does it still fail? And why does resetting the get position solve the problem?

Am I missing something about the workings of a stringstream? Does it set the `eofbit` flag on the last valid read rather than on the read that fails due to EOF? And if so, why does `seekg(0)` seem to clear that flag, while resetting the stringstream doesn't?

Comment: Since you only use `word` inside the loop, why not define it in the scope of the loop (i.e. inside the loop)? A good rule of thumb is to define variables as close to their point of use as possible (which means you should define `number` just before you read into it as well).

Comment: Possible duplicate: [C++ - repeatedly using istringstream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2767298/c-repeatedly-using-istringstream) (calling `word.str()` doesn't reset the iostatus bits)

Comment: I believe it just calls `str(s)` on the buffer, not sure offhand all the effects that has https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringbuf/str . Probably the error flags are completely separate from the buffer, but I am not sure.

Comment: @Adrian-ReinstateMonica I think there is a difference between "you need to call `clear()`" and "why must I call clear?". OP has the `clear()`/working solution.

Comment: @FireLancer Which is why I said *possible* duplicate! 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the state of the stream, this should be a bit clearer.

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> words = { "10", "55", "65" };
    std::istringstream word;
    for (const auto &in : words)
    {
        word.str(in);
        std::cout << "stream state:"
            << (word.rdstate() & std::ios::badbit ? " bad" : "")
            << (word.rdstate() & std::ios::failbit ? " fail" : "")
            << (word.rdstate() & std::ios::eofbit ? " eof" : "")
            << std::endl;
        int number;
        word >> number;

        if (word.fail()) {
            std::cerr << "Failed to read int" << std::endl;
            return 1;
        }

        std::cout << in << ' ' << number << std::endl;
        std::cout << "stream state:"
            << (word.rdstate() & std::ios::badbit ? " bad" : "")
            << (word.rdstate() & std::ios::failbit ? " fail" : "")
            << (word.rdstate() & std::ios::eofbit ? " eof" : "")
            << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Which will result in:

```
stream state:
10 10
stream state: eof
stream state: eof
Failed to read int
```

So initially none of the flags are set, but reading the number reaches the end of the stream, setting `eofbit`. [`std::istringstream::str`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream/str) is defined as if to call [`rdbuf()->str(new_str)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringbuf/str). That says nothing about clearing flags.

Calling `clear()` will of course clear the `eofbit`, but so does calling [`seekg`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg) **in C++11 or newer**. "
Before doing anything else, seekg clears eofbit.    (since C++11)".

Note that if you had say "10 20", that it will just discard the " 20", and not detect an error.

```
stream state:
10 20 10
stream state:
stream state:
55 55
stream state: eof
stream state: eof
Failed to read int
```

So you might actually want to check that eof flag to see if you read the entire stream.

As noted by others, of course constructing a new stream object each loop also means no concerns over previous flags/states.

Comment: So, unlike an fstream, a stringstream essentially looks ahead for the eof and sets `eofbit` in the last valid read?

Comment: @FahimFaisal Not sure what your distinction is here, fstream sets eof the same. as it has to touch the end of stream/file to see that the number is finished, otherwise if it read literally only "10", how does it know it is not actually "100"?

Comment: ```ifstream infile { "myfile.txt" };
    string word;
    while (infile >> word) {
         cout << word << endl;
         if(infile.eof()) cout << "eof" << endl;
         cout << word << endl;
     }```

Comment: If "myfile.txt" consists of a few space separated words, the above code won't print "eof" between printing the last word twice, suggesting that file streams set `eofbit` only on the eof read, rather than the last valid read.

Comment: Same for a string stream though, if I have `std::stringstream ss("10 40\nmore stuff");` then a single `ss >> my_int` *does not set* eof, I have to do multiple reads to get eof, see the "10 20" example output. `10 20 10\nstream state:\n`.

Comment: Yes, I was talking about the last read. Say "myfile.txt" is "a\nb\nc\nd". if `eofbit` is set during the last read, the code should print "a\na\nb\nb\nc\nc\nd\neof\nd\n" since d was the last string. but it prints "a\na\nb\nb\nc\nc\nd\nd\n", suggesting `eofbit` was set on the read attempt after the last string was read.

Comment: You sure you don;t have an extra newline on the file? e.g. https://rextester.com/TVOC70941  (I don't know of an easy to use online C++ with multiple files, but gives me the same result with ifstream if the files are *exactly* as the string).

Comment: Oh, turns out I did have a trailing newline. Without it, it acts the same way as stringstreams, as it should. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

As @Someprogrammerdude suggests: simply move your `istringstream` inside your `while` loop (which you can change to a `for` loop to keep `in` in the loop as well):

```
for (string in; cin >> in;)
{
    istringstream word(in);
    int number;
    if (!(word >> number))
    {
        cerr << "Failed to read int" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    cout << in << ' ' << number << endl;
}
```

that way it's re-created each loop.

While you're at it, move `number` in there too (unless you use it outside the loop, of course).

Comment: Personally I would rather use `istringstream word(in);` instead of the separate call to `str`. Also probably use `if (!(word >> number))` instead of separate extraction and `fail` check. ;)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I shall never use your name in vain. Fixed! :-)